# java howto synchroniz over a group of methods

Tags: java, synchronization

I have three methods that all access the same files in on folder.
I use PersistenceStrategy `com.thoughtworks.xstream.persistence.XmlArrayList`

The thing is that many threads can do write,read,delete using any of the four methods
witch all are synchronized. The synchronized does not stop the READ from one method
colliding with the WRITE in another method since both method are individually synchronized.

Was thinking if i put them all in a Class and synchronize over the Class somehow?

Any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

synchronizing on the MyClass.class instance is acceptable, but in many cases it is preferable to use a private lock rather than something that can be accessed externally. Therefore you can create a private final (static if required) instance and lock on that in your synchronized blocks.

```
private final Object lock = new Object();
```

Comment: Little hard to test i this works since an error in this case is kind of hard to simulate. I think this is the right way to do it. 
synchronize over the: private final PeLock per = new PeLock( );

synchronized (per) {
on = per.loadUserData("name");
}

Comment: don't use a specific type, the lock just needs to be private so an `Object()` is fine. `public class MyClass{ private final Object lock = new Object();public void syncMe(){ synchronized(lock){do stuff();}}}` The lock is a static or instance variable depending on your needs.

Comment: From your example- So you mean i should make three methods syncMe1(), syncMe2(), syncMe3() And only one can be acceptable at any time.
Kind of a controlled "race condition"

Comment: aha very clever..:) The "lock" will block 
Thanks i learned something new

Comment: you said you need synchronization across multiple methods. having a single lock that gets used by all required methods means that only one thread can hold the lock at a time hence only one method can be executing at a time. In your case you can force it so that any of the read, update or delete methods can be accessed but only one at a time.